# How to build NextJS to es5?

Tags: typescript, next.js

Is there anyway to build a nextjs app for es5? I only need the exported static javascript to be es5 since I need to support a device that only has es5. I tried adding a babel polyfill, but when I ran es-check on _app file, it still had arrow functions and es6 features.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the browserslist configuration to do that.

In your `package.json`, add the following:

```json
{
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.3%, defaults, supports es5"
  ]
}
```

- [Nextjs docs reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features)
- [Browserslist Playground](https://browsersl.ist/)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Next.js 13? If I run `next build && next export && cd out && grep -rl '=>' .`, it still lists `.js` files containing ES6 arrows.

Comment: It seems to be working on my local and also on an online sandbox. Did you delete `.next` and `out` directories before re-running the command? Here is the link to a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-saha-3skvx6)

Comment: Thanks! Deleting `.next` did the trick. (I opened a [bug](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43241) for this.)

Comment: I also noticed that "browserslist" doesn't seem to be honored in npm dependencies, so a bunch of incompatible code ended up in my distribution nonetheless. I opened [another bug](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/43246) for this.

Comment: @vighnesh153 does not work for NextJS 14 and IE 11

Comment: @north.inhale Looks like a bug to me. You can file a bug on their [github repository](https://github.com/vercel/next.js)

Comment: @vighnesh153 I think it so, because it doesn’t work out from the box, the built code contains strings template literals which Internet Explorer 11 does not recognise